# Multidimensional array in a loop prepending one 0 then two 0's then tree 0's etc

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im kinda stuck on this for a few hours. I need every time the loop, loops throught the weeks adding a extra "0" to the multidimensional array.

for example this is what i wanna achievev

```
Array
(
    [week1] => Array // Week 1 do nothing
        (
            [0] => 0.461718
            [1] => 2.874501
            [2] => 4.968576
            [3] => 4.353633
            [4] => 3.019554
            [5] => 2.026656
            [6] => 1.405584
            [7] => 1.119564
            [8] => 1.131822
        )

    [week2] => Array // Week 2 prepend one "0"
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0.461718
            [2] => 2.874501
            [3] => 4.968576
            [4] => 4.353633
            [5] => 3.019554
            [6] => 2.026656
            [7] => 1.405584
            [8] => 1.119564
            [9] => 1.131822
        )

    [week3] => Array // Week 3 prepend two "0's"
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0.461718
            [3] => 2.874501
            [4] => 4.968576
            [5] => 4.353633
            [6] => 3.019554
            [7] => 2.026656
            [8] => 1.405584
            [9] => 1.119564
            [10] => 1.131822
        )

    [week3] => Array // Week 4 prepend three "0's"
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0.461718
            [4] => 2.874501
            [5] => 4.968576
            [6] => 4.353633
            [7] => 3.019554
            [8] => 2.026656
            [9] => 1.405584
            [10] => 1.119564
            [11] => 1.131822
        )

        // Etc...
```

This is my code.
I get now in every array only one "0"

```
$totaal = array();

    for($w = 1; $w <= 52; $w++)
    {
        for($sw = 0; $sw <= 8; $sw++)
        {           
            $totaal["week".$w][] = $vruchtzettings_week["week".$w][$sw];
        }
    }

   for($w = 1; $w <= 52; $w++)
   {
        $sum = 0;

        array_unshift($totaal["week".$w], $sum);

        for($sw = 0; $sw <= 8; $sw++)
        {           
            echo $totaal["week".$w][$sw]."<br />";

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$increments = 0;
foreach ($weeks as &$week) {
    if ($increments > 0) {
        for ($i=0; $i< $increments; $i++) {
            array_unshift($week, 0);
        }
    }
    $increments++;
}
```

EDIT: Changed <= to < in the for loop

More in depth response:

```
// If I'm not mistaken $vruchtzettings_week contains all your
// data up to 52 weeks.  You're first transferring this data
// to a variable, $totaal, by looping through it's contents.  But
// why not just set $totaal equal to $vruchtzettings_week?
$totaal = $vruchtzettings_week; // tada!

$increments = 0;
foreach ($totaal as &$data) { // We make a reference of $data so any changes are preserved
    if ($increments > 0) {
        for ($i=0; $i< $increments; $i++) {
            array_unshift($data, 0);
        }
    }
    $increments++;
}

var_dump($totaal); // Total now looks like what you wanted

/*
Array
(
[week1] => Array // Week 1 do nothing
    (
        [0] => 0.461718
        [1] => 2.874501
        [2] => 4.968576
        [3] => 4.353633
        [4] => 3.019554
        [5] => 2.026656
        [6] => 1.405584
        [7] => 1.119564
        [8] => 1.131822
    )

[week2] => Array // Week 2 prepend one "0"
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0.461718
        [2] => 2.874501
        [3] => 4.968576
        [4] => 4.353633
        [5] => 3.019554
        [6] => 2.026656
        [7] => 1.405584
        [8] => 1.119564
        [9] => 1.131822
    )
    etc...
    */
```

In answer to the comment below:  The following will fill an array with the sum of the weeks data, where each successive index includes the sum of data from all weeks previous.

```
$totaal_part1 = array();
foreach ($totaal as $i => $data) {
    $totaal_part1[] = array_sum($data) + (isset($totaal_part1[$i - 1]) ? $totaal_part1[$i - 1] : 0);
}
```

Comment: can you show me with my example pls, i dont getting it fit togetter

Comment: Looks like this works :D now i need to calculate all the week togetter for example $totaal_part1[1] = week 1, $totaal_part1[2] = week 1 + week 2, $totaal_part1[3] = week 1 + week 2 + week 3 etc... up to 52 Whats the best way to do that ?

Comment: Thanks man, youre good ! i dont understand everything what you did but i will study it and try to understand

Comment: mm i dont get the exspected result the result should be like:[0] => 0.461718 [1] => 3.336219 (week 1[1] + week 2[1]) etc...

Comment: Im getting $totaal_part1[0] = 21.361608, $totaal_part1[1] = 21.361608 etc... all the same results

Comment: You didn't specify you wanted to add together each day of the week. My example is adding together the sum of all days of a week.  And if you're getting the same value in each index, you're probably overwriting your values somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is not very elegant, but should work:

```
$totaal = array();

    for($w = 1; $w <= 52; $w++)
    {
        for($sw = 0; $sw <= 8; $sw++)
        {           
            $totaal["week".$w][] = $vruchtzettings_week["week".$w][$sw];
        }
    }

   for($w = 1; $w <= 52; $w++)
   {
        $sum = 0;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $w; $i++) array_unshift($totaal["week".$w], $sum);

        for($sw = 0; $sw <= 8; $sw++)
        {           
            echo $totaal["week".$w][$sw]."<br />";

        }
    }
```

Comment: Youre solution replaces the existing value's, i need them to prepend and keep the existing ones